# PRXMATCH in SAS EG don't work in open code

Tags: sas

I have this little code in SAS EG open code, it gives me 0 in A and I don't understand why!!!

```
%let ph=FONDS DE BOURSE;
%LET A=%sysfunc(PRXMATCH("/bourse/i","&ph"));
%put &A;
```

The result :

```
         %let ph=FONDS DE BOURSE;
         %LET A=%sysfunc(PRXMATCH("/bourse/i","&ph"));
SYMBOLGEN:  La macro-variable PH est résolue en FONDS DE BOURSE
         %put &A;
SYMBOLGEN:  La macro-variable A est résolue en 0
0
```

Please, can you help ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using macros, you do not need to use quotation marks for string arguments in functions. Quotation marks are passed exactly as-is to `PRXMATCH` since the SAS macro facility is designed to process raw text. Remove your quotation marks and it will work as expected.

```
%let ph=FONDS DE BOURSE;
%LET A=%sysfunc(PRXMATCH(/bourse/i,&ph));
%put &A;
```

When using a data step, you will need to use quotation marks for the first part of the argument. Unquoted strings are processed as variables.

```
data test;
    ph='FONDS DE BOURSE';
    A=PRXMATCH("/bourse/i", ph);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer and explanation!